# angular build errors in docker image

Tags: angular, docker

I have angular 6 application. It builds and works with no issue locally.

Now I want to create docker image. I'm following this guide https://medium.com/@tiangolo/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984

The issue is that application can't find some modules when dockerizing it (fails on 7 step). When I run command from this step in console, it builds normally. How can I approach this? I'm fighting this 2 days now.

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/

ARG configuration=production

RUN npm run build -- --output-path=./dist/out --configuration $configuration

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Please provide your code and a reproducible result. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry my connection frozen, does it help now?

Comment: no it does not help, you need to physically type the contents of your `Dockerfile` in to your question. Screenshots do not help in this case

Comment: I think that dockerfile is not copying all components to image-source directory. I don't know how to check that or fix, so this is only my guess

Comment: I doubt your project files are copied over, stop your dockerfile from building after copying files over then run `docker build . -t test-app` and then `docker run -it test-app bash` you'll get a terminal in your docker container. Check if all files are there and correct

Comment: I'm developing on windows, and it's treats same way upper and lower cases in dir paths. Apparently unix system not. That was the issue. Thanks for taking time

Comment: NP, please take my answer as best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue for OP as it was a problem with case sensitivity with paths.

Answer (score 0):

Everything points out that the npm install command is missing before step 7. Please add this step on the dockerfile prior to the the ng build command.

Comment: I've added dockerfile. It runs npm install before